# export to excel not working - java, struts,jquery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, export-to-excel

Export to Excel doesn't seem to open the dialog box asking for if I should save or open. Here is the code.

```
try
        {
            String wc = getJsonParameter("ids");    

            WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(out);

            workbook.setColourRGB(Colour.GREY_25_PERCENT, 240, 240, 240);

            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Excel Report", 0);          

            eReports = workCenterService.getStkRoom(wc);

            SpreadsheetWc excelReport = SpreadsheetWc.getMsgSpreadsheet();
            excelReport.buildSpreadsheet(sheet, eReports);

            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();

            setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) out).toByteArray()));

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            returnCode = 10;
        }
        catch (WriteException e)
        {
            returnCode = 99;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
```

In struts.xml I have mentioned the content disposition.

```
<action name="wcExcel" class="com.i9nframework.master.IdAction" method="excelReport">           
            <result type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment; filename="Excel Report.xls"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

In JS the following code has been given

```
  async: asynchVar,
            success : function(response) {  

                $("#messageDiv").html("<div class='R'>Generating Spreadsheet, " +
                "this can take several minutes.</div>").show().delay(10000).slideUp();
                window.open = "excelReport?" + queryStr;
            }
        });
```

Any leads to fix this ?I could see this can take several minutes after which nothing happens

Comment: Of course it nothing happens because response object is unused.

Comment: @RomanC can you please tell me how to use the response object ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a response? it's for for requests that are getting something back with the request but you in your case it's just doesn't work.

Comment: Why js? Use a plain link/form.